# How to run chromium os on Hyper‑V without compiling anything?

Tags: graphics-card, hyper-v, google-chrome-os, scsi, remotefx

Since Windows 8, Hyper‑V supports booting uefi systems provided the hard drive is emulated under an scsi controller, the result is if I download a build from http://chromium.arnoldthebat.co.uk/ everything hangs at this stage *(after booting the kernel)* :
[image]
I have a Slylake cpu, so I doubt an illegal instruction is involved.

The problem is I have other ᴠᴍ using Hyper‑V the Hyper‑V hypervisor is exclusive on Windows : you need to uninstall Hyerp‑V in order to let an other Hypervisor being able to use virtualization instruction of the processor.
Does someone has an idea to fix this ? I need an image that support verified booting.

Comment: What OS are you running on? How do you detect it hangs? Why do you need an image that has "verified booting"?

Comment: @Seth I need to test the verifying booting feature itself. The image above is the first one printed on the screen and also the last one, I mean I can leave it running during hours and nothing changes, the keyboard has no effect. The only possibility is to power off the vm. I am using Windows 10 professional.

Comment: You have verified, that the image in question is x86 Chromium image that supports UEFI?  If you have not then you should, and if it doesn't, the you have to make the required changes and compile it to achieve your task

Comment: @Ramhound : Sighh :(. Chromium ᴏꜱ isn’t Android but a Linux distribution 
 based on Gentoo. Otherwise yes, ᴜᴇꜰɪ is the only way to boot vanilla builds.

Comment: My question remains the same even though I use the wrong word.. Is it a x86 build?

Comment: @Ramhound : yes it’s an ᴀᴍᴅ⁶⁴ build, and as you can see on the picture above, ɢʀᴜʙ2 is correctly loaded by Hyper‑V. I also tried special and vanilla builds from http://chromium.arnoldthebat.co.uk/. I Just guess they don’t support the graphic driver required for Hyper‑V and I failed to find an image which both supports verified booting and the 3D RemoteFx emulated graphic card.

Comment: [related](https://superuser.com/q/1101691/282033).

Comment: Nothing in your question (body) indicates your trying to install a 64-bit build of Chromium

Comment: @Ramhound : having a 64 bits bootloader is requirement for ᴜᴇꜰɪ booting on Hyper‑V. If not, the picture above would show the ᴠᴍ tryng to boot from  pxe.